# iOS - setting NSDate for localization using shorthand for the day

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So i would like to set the date into a label with the following format

Mon, Nov 17, 2014. Tue,... Wed... (depending on which day)

Now I can get this from the following setDateFormat:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, yyyy"];
```

When i change settings however(lets say Denmark), I obviously still get Mon, Nov 17, 2014.

I havent found a date style that is going to give me what i need here. Is the best solution to get the day of the week and then add that shorthand to the beginning of the NSDateFormatterMediumStyle for the normal Month, day, year or am I missing something in the docs that would give me what i want here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You want a localized version of the date string that always has the name of the day at the start?

Comment: yeah so for like the Dutch example, normally the date reads like 17, Nov, 2014 using NSDateFormatterMediumStyle. In my case i would like for it to read Mon, 17 Nov 2014 or whatever the shorthand for days of the week is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired results by doing the following:

```
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEE, MMM d, yyyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
```

`format` will be adjusted to best suit the current locale.

Comment: hey that looked like it worked perfectly. Ive tried different weekdays , it looks like Mon for the United States still reads 'Mon' for Swedish and Dutch just the same. Do these different locales use different shorthands for days of the week?? Example: Måndag is Monday in Swedish but its showing 'Mon, 17 Nov 2014'

Comment: What language is set on the device/simulator? If needed, you can override the device/simulator's language by setting a specific locale.

Comment: yeah i just changed the region but not the language so once i changed it it worked fine. thanks for the quick help! Accepted. How would I override the device language? I dont need it to be a specfic langugage - it would need to be dynamic based on the locale.. thanks